# horizontal scroll on second div

Tags: html, css, scroll, responsive-design

I am stuck at a problem. I have created a section which looks like an HTML table. But I haven't use the "table" tag for that.

I have purely used HTML and CSS to achieve the said goal. Now the problem is I am not able to make it responsive. I know I can make it responsive by simply using overflow property. But I don't want to scroll on the whole section. I just want horizontal scroll on right side of the section. In my example, it is the class namely right-content which I want scrollable. The class namely left-content must be there so that if I scroll the right side the left side must be fixed there, user can see it.

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
```

I am attaching the codepen link for accessibility of whole code.

https://codepen.io/Mehreen_Fayaz/pen/KjNoMG

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly if this is what you're looking for, but you can simply make the section with class `right-content` scrollable with `overflow: scroll;`. It would help if there was content inside the section so you can test the desired result.

Comment: I have kept it as you mentioned but still i am not getting desired results

Answer (score 0):

I think you're honestly setting the `flex-basis` property more times than is useful and that's causing your problems.

Using `flex-grow`/`flex-shrink` to allow space to be taken up the element or be squished is better than trying to be overly precise with changing the `flex-basis` from an `auto` value.

For your exact case, these changes should fix some of the strangeness you see on narrow screens...

- Remove `display: flex` from `.outer-wrapper`
- Remove `flex-basis: 74%` from `.right-content` and just set `flex: 0 1 75%`
- Just always have `overflow-x: auto;` on `.right-content`, you don't need the media query
- Remove `flex-basis: 26%` from `.left-content` and just set `flex: 1 0 auto`
- Remove the `flex-basis: 20%` from `.right-content .head` and just set `flex: 1`

This should solve most of the "over-engineered" layout things, and then the last thing I would suggest would be to add some padding around the "table cells" so that on small screens the text won't run right into the sides of themselves, giving some breathing room. But you might also needs to set `box-sizing: border-box` on them so that padding will push into the text instead of push out from the width/height values you have set.

Good luck.